# Rd RX810 compatible 1x?

Tags: shimano, gravel

I was just wondering if the Rd rx810 is compatible with a 1x 42t and 11-40 set up? I've seen it's meant just for 2x but wondered if that was just shimano being shimano.

Thanks!

Comment: The derailleur’s B-offset is set according to the cassette it’s expected to be paired with. With a too-large cassette, the guide pulley won’t get out of the way enough.

Answer (score 2):

### No, not officially.

The authorative document is https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/grx-11-speed/RD-RX810.html which says

| MODEL NO | RD-RX810 |
| --- | --- |
| SERIES | GRX 11-speed |
| Low sprocket_Max. | 34T |
| Low sprocket_Min. | 30T |
| Max. front difference | 17T |
| Top sprocket_Min and Max. | 11T |
| Total capacity | 40T |

So the minimum and maximum tooth count on your cassette is 11.  That says it has to be 11 tooth.

At the big end, minimum is 30 and maximum is 34 tooth.  Since your desired 40 tooth is more, its out of spec.

Can you make it work?   40 is a long way from 34, and while you could probably push it to 36 without issue, 38 is getting iffy and 40 is unlikely.  It may be possible with a derailleur extender like a tanpan or wolfs tooth, but then you're compromising somewhere else.  Read on...

---

Separately there's the part of the question about is this going to work with a single chainring.

I'd guess that you're not exceeding capacity, so its nominally no worse than simply riding on one chainring of a double.  You're only using `34-11=23` teeth of capacity.  However the rated "40T capacity" is not all in the rear cassette, its up to 23 teeth in the cassette and up to 17 teeth in the chainring difference.

---

**Upshot** 42:34 is not a terrible gear for climbing, but its nowhere near the sub-1:1 range like a triple could give, and not approaching what a compact double could do.  All depends what you want to ride up and how fast.

**Answer** You want a RD-RX812 which has a 40 or 42 tooth low gear rating.  That would let you use 42:40 as per your question.  You need an 11 speed chain as well, and an 11 speed GRX shifter that suits your bars and brakes.  Downside, 42:11 isn't going to spin you fast on a downhill or a tailwind, but they're not as common with offroad riding so less of an issue.

<sup>I'd consider going **42:42** cos the meaning of life at both ends of your transmission is fantastically nerdy.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your very in depth answer, that's cleared things up a lot.